# WebStorm run command or program on project open

Tags: webstorm

Is there any way to run external program or command after I open project in WebStorm?

I've created new external tool which runs database server, and after I click on it in menu, it runs the server and everything works, but I'd like to start this tool automatically on project start. And it'd be awesome if it could also open web browser to certain url which would be database admin tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can launch your desired task using Grunt/Gulp/npm task or any other Run/Debug Configuration then yes -- there is **Startup Tasks** functionality available at `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Startup Tasks`.

**Note** that you cannot execute External Tools entry directly or launch any DOS/shell command this way.

The easiest way of using this would be creating Grunt/Gulp task that would do your actual job. There you can use `exec()` method to execute custom command.

Comment: And can Gulp (which I'm using) run exe program?

Comment: gulp-run, gulp-exec, gulp-shell to name a few (have not used any of them myself though). On another hand (if you want to just run something -- use `exec` task/method directly).