# Run python file when PyCharm opens

Tags: python, automation, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to run two Python Scripts when PyCharm Professional Opens. Ideally, the program would not run in the PyCharm console. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please check if [Startup Tasks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-startup-tasks.html) to execute some stuff **on project opening**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35279889/783119. If you can run such script using any of the Run/Debug Configurations, then it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Running two python files on the PyCharm Professional easy.

For instance:

This is my first `main.py` file:

[image]

Then I right-click on the PyCharm Professional, open the 2nd project

[image]

PyCharm asks me:

[image]

Click on the New Window button. Now you have two windows next to each other:

[image]

You can either run or debug both of them at the same time.

[image]

From above you can see, PyCharm executes both files at the same time.

You can also do this in the same project or you can run or debug multiple projects at the same time